# Approximate Change of Basis Matrix/ Solution to Algebraic Riccatti System

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $B,Q,P$ be compatible matrices.  Is there a closed-form solution to 
$$
\|PBB^TP^T -M\|_{F}=0;
$$
where $F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Ideas:

- Solve the *simplified* algebraic Riccati equation
  $$
  PBB^TP^T =M?
  $$
- Proximal Mapping Approach.

However, I've found no solution to the "closest change of matrix P" making B into $M$...

Comment: Note: it should exist since the objective function is lsc, convex, proper, and bounded-below by $0$.

Comment: @AIM_BLB Since you have replaced $BB^T$ with $B$, we have lost the information that your $B$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, which is important to the problem.

Comment: @MrMMS can we assume that both $B$ and $M$ are symmetric and positive semidefinite?  Do we have any information about the ranks of $B$ and $M$?

Comment: Indeed we can (I put B back in for this reason).  There is no information on their ranks...  But we can treat the general case and the specific case where $M$ and $BB^T$ are of full-rank separately if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, per the comments, that $M$ is (symmetric and) positive semidefinite.

By [Sylvester's law of intertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), an exact solution to $P(BB^T)P^T = M$ will exist if and only if the rank of $M$ is less than or equal to the rank of $BB^T$, which must in turn be equal to the rank of $B$.  We can characterize every solution to this equation as follows:

- Let $LL^T = M$ be a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).
- For some orthogonal matrix $Q$ (we could simply take $Q = I$ for instance), $P$ must solve the linear equation $PB = LQ$.

If the rank of $M$ is greater than that of $B$, then I we can find a minimizer to $\|PBB^TP^T - M\|_F$ as follows:  Let $r$ denote the rank of $B$.  Find the [best rank-$r$ approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem) to $M$ (using a truncated SVD or truncated spectral decomposition), call this low-rank matrix $\tilde M$.  Then, a $P$ solving $P(BB^T)P^T = \tilde M$ will minimize our objective function.

Comment: But how can we solve the last bit since $P$ need not be orthogonal?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Why do we care about $P$ being orthogonal?

Comment: But if $P$ is orthogonal then $P(BB^T)P^{-1}=P(BB^T)P^T=M$ is a basis change problem (which we can compute using standard linear algebra).  But in general, I don't know how to solve $P(BB^T)P^T=M$...

Comment: @MrMMS I've added something about that to the first part of my answer

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  Also, I guess this doesn't work for other component-wise $p$-norms if $p\neq 2$?

Comment: @MrMMS Of course the exact solution still works, but the approximation trick does not.  By Mirsky's result, however, the same approximation trick will work for any unitarily invariant matrix norm.  For instance, it will work for all [Schatten norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms).  The Schatten 1-norm (AKA the "nucelar norm" or "trace norm") is a prominent example of a Schatten norm used in numerical linear algebra.

Comment: You could extend this method to non-unitarily invariant norms if you can compute the closest rank-$r$ approximation to $M$ relative to that norm.  However, this is generally a difficult problem.

Comment: Thank you this has been very helpful! :)